# How to pass client side data to express which calls remote url and get the response back

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

How to pass $scope object in http.get() to express and get the data. Here is my Code and can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?
So the endpoint url is http://myhost:8080/employees/123. Here I need to pass the empID dynamically from my controller to express server. My code works without passing empid and gets the complete list.

angularJs controller

```
$scope.eid = "123";
$http.get('/employees/:empId=' + $scope.eid)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.employeeInfo = data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
    });
```

server-side code

```js
app.get("/employees/:empId", function(req,res) {
        
        var ServerOptions = {
            host: 'myHost',
            port: 8000,
            path: '/employees/:empId',
            method: 'GET'
        };
        var Request = http.request(ServerOptions,       function (Response) {
            ...
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the angular code you should:

```
$scope.eid = "123";
$http.get('/employees/' + $scope.eid)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.employeeInfo = data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
    });
```

and in express

```
 app.get("/employees/:empId", function(req,res) {

    var ServerOptions = {
        host: 'myHost',
        port: 8000,
        path: '/employees/' + req.params.empId,
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var Request = http.request(ServerOptions,       function (Response) {
        ...
    });

});
```

Comment: I have passed it like above at first but not sure it wasn't calling the server side code. Do you suggest making any changes in the server side code?

Comment: I made the change like above and still don't get any response

Comment: try instead of req.params.empId to use req.param("empId") in case you are using an older version of express

Comment: if you just put    path: '/employees/123',    in express does it work?

Comment: You are right! I am not getting any response back even though I see the response for it in fiddler

Comment: I just tried to call the endpoint from controller instead of going though express but I don't get any response back. $http.get('http://myHost:8000/employees/123')
        .success(function (data, status)   ....Do you think this is a CORS issue?

Comment: It could be. Check it out.

Comment: Looks like it is not Express Issue. I just did $http.get('/employees/' + $scope.eid)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.employeeInfo = data; console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data, status) {
    }); ... And I am getting data in the console but the scope.employeeInfo is undefined. @Giannis.. Do you know why the $scope.employeeInfo is undefined?

Comment: So in the place you write $scope.employeeInfo = data; if you log the data it is there but if you log the $scope.employeeInfo it is not?